# Is String interned using .intern() is Garbage collected?

Tags: java, string, string-literals

I executed the following piece of code

```
class Test{
    static void func(){
        String s="str";
        long i=0;
        while(true){
            String s1=s+i++;
            s1.intern();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func();
    }
}
```

When executing the above code using the following command -

```
java -Xmx1m Test
```

It seems to work infinitely, which makes me think that the interned strings might be Garbage collected.

So my question is that is there any way that the GC might collect the interned strings, or something else is happening in the above code?

Comment: "It seems to work infinitely" - that's very subjective. How many iterations did you allow that loop to run?

Comment: [Java String Pool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool) - *From Java 7 onwards, the Java String Pool is stored in the Heap space, which is garbage collected by the JVM. The advantage of this approach is the reduced risk of OutOfMemory error because unreferenced Strings will be removed from the pool, thereby releasing memory.*

Comment: @Eran I added a print statement to print `i` inside the while loop and stopped the execution after around 15sec and it ran for 846568 iterations

Comment: String S1 will be GC as soon as the iteration of loop is completed becase the scope of string ends there.As for Infinite iterations, are you waiting for OutOfMemory error to stop your execution ?

Comment: @EkamjitSingh - Not really true. While this is true for *common strings*, that string is ***interned***, which before java 7 meant inserting it into a string pool inside the PermGen space, which is **not** eligible for garbage collection. Starting from java 7 the string pool has been moved to heap. So it is true that the string is garbage collected, but the reason is not that its scope ends there, it is that the string is not kept in PermGen space anymore.

Comment: @BackSlash- Thanks for clarifying.